# how to display title in TOC and in actual content page slightly differently

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I have some characters that I want to show up in TOC but not in actual content page. Is there any commands to wrap around these characters when defining chapter title so that they will be excluded in the content page but still show up properly in TOC?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the optional form `\chapter[to appear in toc]{to display on the document}`

Comment: I have another question. Say I have \chapter[t1]{t2}. Now the page header shows t1, can I force to use t2 in the heading?

Comment: You could modify heading with fancyhdr package. If you have problems doing so, post another question (to get more visibility).

Comment: Thanks, I started another thread on that. This should be closed for now.

Answer (score 2):

Per Sigur's suggestion: "Use the optional form \chapter[to appear in toc]{to display on the document}"

Copy & paste Sigur's reply due to short message rule on SO.